# exchange hybrid, management server do I still need HCW/Agent?

Tags: microsoft-office-365, exchange-2016, office365

we currently migrated all our mailboxes into the cloud and want to keep one single exchange server (a pretty clean one) after our migration. do we still need the HCW Hybrid Agent or can we remove it aswell after we migrated everything and only want to keep the last exchange server 2016 for management purposes?

we followed the following guide: https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/exchange/decommission-on-premises-exchange

Edit:

I meant Hybrid Configuration Wizard and Hybrid Service inside Programs and Features

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean removing the Hybrid Configuration or removing the Hybrid Configuration Wizard from Programs and Features?
You can follow this blog to remove Hybrid Configuration with command Remove-HybridConfiguration: https://blog.rmilne.ca/2020/07/15/remove-hybridconfiguration-cmdlet/

Comment: that's what I already did but there is still Hybrid Configuration Wizard and Hybrid Service inside Programs and Features